# i'm getting this error when deploying my python application to heroku and its driving me crazy

Tags: python, flask, heroku

i'm getting this error when i try to deploy my python application to heroku.
I have python 3.8.2 installed and it is available for the stack.

(venvm) C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\Watstwilio>git push heroku master

```
> Enumerating objects: 3284, done. Counting objects: 100% (3284/3284),
> done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads Compressing objects:
> 100% (3250/3250), done. Writing objects: 100% (3284/3284), 19.41 MiB |
> 942.00 KiB/s, done. Total 3284 (delta 916), reused 0 (delta 0) remote: Compressing source files... done. remote: Building source: remote:
> remote: -----> Python app detected remote:  !     Requested runtime
> (python-3.8) is not available for this stack (heroku-18). remote:  !  
> Aborting.  More info:
> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support remote:  !    
> Push rejected, failed to compile Python app. remote: remote:  !    
> Push failed remote: Verifying deploy... remote: remote: !       Push
> rejected to whatsapbot. remote: To
> https://git.heroku.com/whatsapbot.git  ! [remote rejected] master ->
> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to
> 'https://git.heroku.com/whatsapbot.git'
```

My requirements.txt looks like:

```
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
Flask==1.1.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.9
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.23.0
six==1.14.0
twilio==6.35.5
urllib3==1.25.8
Werkzeug==1.0.0
```

and runtime.txt looks like this:

```
python-3.8.2
```

I also noticed that the error doesn't mention the full version of my installed python it says: 'Requested runtime (python-3.8)'.

I've tried reinstalling python but to no avail. What am i doing wrong? Please help!!!

Comment: Open a support ticket at Heroku. http://help.heroku.com/ It should be supported: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes "`python-3.8.2` on all supported runtime stacks"

Comment: Heroku doesn't allow non-paying customers to open support tickets. So can't get any specific support from them. Read through their existing help but coudn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Non paying customers can open tickets. The reasoning for opening tickets is however limited. I'm not saying you should do it but if you open a ticket in the wrong category they will forward your ticket to the correct category.